# How to check in .htaccess if PHP is enabled?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I let Apache's `.htaccess` file check if PHP is enabled? I tried things like `<IfModule !mod_php7.0.c>` and `<IfModule !mod_php7.c>` but it doesn not seem to do anything when I enable/disable the module.

I would like to have a fallback in my `.htaccess` that denies acces from all when PHP is disabled. In order to prevent leakage of plain text PHP code.

I want to do something like this:

```
# If PHP is not installed, deny all access to .php files to prevent PHP code leakage
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Ultimately it will check something like `if php7 AND php5 AND php4 are disabled, deny access`. Any ideas?

*Also, when AllowOverride is None and so the `.htaccess` file is not doing anything. What are the options in order to prevent the PHP code from leaking in plaintext?*

Comment: The trick (best practice) is not putting PHP sourcecode in the `public_html` folder ;-) That way both your cases are resolved properly.

Comment: I already did this. I only put the index.php file which basically includes stuff from outside the public_html folder. But I assume I can move everything and have one php file that includes another outside the root. In that case in the worst case, a one-liner php file with one include leaks. Right?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways, the one you mentioned is probably the easiest and simplest one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

In Apache 2.4

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

In Apache 2.4 there are several new useful features: [define](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#define), [ifdefine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ifdefine), and [if, else, ifelse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if).

In the following we can deny by default and only enable if `PHP_IS_ENABLED` is defined.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    Define PHP_IS_ENABLED
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    Define PHP_IS_ENABLED
</IfModule>

# php8
<IfModule mod_php.c>
    Define PHP_IS_ENABLED
</IfModule>

# ...

<IfDefine !PHP_IS_ENABLED>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if mod_php5 is not loaded but PHP 4 or 7 is?

Comment: In apache 2.4 I think we can take advantage of some new features to get what you want.

Comment: `Define` is not allowed in `.htaccess`

Comment: @cronfy The `Define` keyword is only allowed in server config and virtual host configurations. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#define.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution to check against multiple versions of PHP (e.g. "if php 5 **OR** php 7 is enabled") that indeed works in `.htaccess`.

It requires Apache 2.4 with `mod_env` module (99% it is enabled on your host).

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    SetEnv PHP_IS_ENABLED yes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    SetEnv PHP_IS_ENABLED yes
</IfModule>

<If "reqenv('PHP_IS_ENABLED') == 'yes' || reqenv('REDIRECT_PHP_IS_ENABLED') == 'yes'">
    ... your directives
</If>
```

`REDIRECT_PHP_IS_ENABLED` is required to make this work for requests internally redirected with mod_rewrite.

Comment: I tried this on RHEL 7 using httpd24u-2.4.41-1.el7.ius and php72u-fpm-httpd-7.2.27-1, confirmed I have mod_env.c, and had to revert to using only <IfModule></IfModule>.  It was easy to tell it didn't work as php_fpm blew up and returned error 500s when it didn't work.

Comment: @kbulgrien mod_php and php-fpm are different things, this may be the reason. The answer is for mod_php only.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the <If></If> logic didn't work.  The answer/comments are applicable.  I was trying to detect mod_php and use php_value directive if it was loaded.  This was needed to disable the php_value directives in cases where php-fpm was used, in which case the .user.ini was used instead.  I had to remove the <If></If> and depend on the multiple version-specific <IfModule></IfModule> even though the <If></If> logic would have been much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a refinement on [cronfy's answer for `.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031283/13508) that I use to set PHP directives that need to be set before the scripts runs, thus cannot be set from within code (e.g. `ini_set()`):

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    SetEnv MOD_PHP 5
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    SetEnv MOD_PHP 7
</IfModule>
<If "reqenv('MOD_PHP') != '' || reqenv('REDIRECT_MOD_PHP') != ''">
    php_value post_max_size 100M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
</If>
```

Such directives need to be synced with those in `.user.ini`:

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

Comment: I tried this on RHEL 7 using httpd24u-2.4.41-1.el7.ius and php72u-fpm-httpd-7.2.27-1, confirmed I have mod_env.c, and had to revert to using only <IfModule></IfModule>.  It was easy to tell it didn't work as php_fpm blew up and returned error 500s when it didn't work.

Comment: @kbulgrien `fpm`, like all other CGI-based interfaces, doesn't accept PHP directives from Apache configuration. You need to use `.user.ini` (or a version-wide php.ini file). Whatever, I've no idea of what your exact problem was - Error 500 just means "check the logs".

Comment: What I'm saying is that the <If></If> logic didn't work.  The answer and comments are applicable.  I was trying to detect mod_php and use php_value directive if it was loaded.  This was needed to disable the php_value directives in cases where php-fpm was used, in which case the .user.ini was used instead.  I had to remove the <If></If> and depend on the multiple version-specific <IfModule></IfModule> even though the <If></If> logic would have been much nicer.  The 500 error was because the php_value directives that should have been disabled were not disabled.

Comment: @kbulgrien Did you check the logs? It'd be interesting to see what exactly it was complaining about. `<If>` is a core directive and should definitively exist on Apache/2.4.41 :-?