# Set and check an environment variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, environment-variables, apache2

I am trying to set an environment variable depending on if PHP is running as an apache module from within an `.htaccess` file. Dumping out the `$_SERVER` array in the php script I can see that the `MOD_PHP` variable is successfully set, but the `reqenv()` condition always seems to return false, since `ini_get('memory_limit');` still reports the default value.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    SetEnv MOD_PHP php5
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    SetEnv MOD_PHP php7
</IfModule>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    <If "reqenv('MOD_PHP') != '' || reqenv('REDIRECT_MOD_PHP') != ''">
        php_value memory_limit 1024M
    </If>
</IfVersion>
```

Not sure why the above is not working. If I move the `php_value` right beneath the `<IfVersion>` section then the value is modified as expected:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    SetEnv MOD_PHP php5
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    SetEnv MOD_PHP php7
</IfModule>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
# the following works
php_value memory_limit 1024M
</IfVersion>
```

So it seems to have something do to with the `<If "reqenv()">` part.

I am running php 7.2.13 on ubuntu 14.04 with apache 2.4.7 installed.

I might also add that I *am* running PHP as an apache module.

Comment: take a look   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450760/how-to-check-in-htaccess-if-php-is-enabled/51535081#51535081

Comment: @manny - And if you look on the above you can see that it is almost identical, but it is still not working, so the link is not helping in this case =)

Comment: Hope you noted this points....Such directives need to be synced with those in .user.ini: , i mean do you set this "memory_limit 1024M"  in .ini file?

Comment: It does **not** need to be synced with those in the `.user.ini` file, as I understand it the `.user.ini` file will only be used if running php in `CGI/FastCGI` mode, which I don't. You can also see in my question that it is indeed working if I just set the php setting directly from within the `<IfVersion>` section.

Answer (score 0):

`SetEnv` happens very late, before `<if>` is evaluated.

`SetEnvIf` happens much earlier, before `<if>` is evaluated.

Use SetEnvIf if you want to set an per-request environment variable early enough to check it with `<if>`. Or, use a real environment variable (defined in e.g. the `envvars` file distributed with httpd) if the variable is not per-request at all.

Comment: So what can I do to solve this? Right now you answer is not a solution =)

Comment: Use SetEnvIf if you want to set an per-request environment variable early enough to check it with <if>

Comment: So how can I use SetEnvIf to set a variabel when a module is enabeled?